# PHP output in html

Tags: php

I am trying to post result of php in text box of same page but have no clue to do so. Code is below

```
    <form action = "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method = "GET" >
         Input1: <input type = "text" name = "input1" />
         Input2: <input type = "text" name = "input2" />
         Result: <input type = "text" name = "result" />

         <input type = "submit" />


    </form>
```

Complete Code:

```
<?php 
$input1 = $_GET["input1"]; 
$input2 = $_GET["input2"]; 
$result = $input1 + $input2; 
echo "$result"; 
?> 
<html> 
<body> 
<form action = "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method = "GET" > 
    Input1: <input type = "text" name = "input1" /> 
    Input2: <input type = "text" name = "input2" /> 
    Result: <input type = "text" name = "result" /> 
    <input type = "submit" /> 
</form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

I want to show $result in result textbox.
Thanks.

Comment: Where is `$result` set?

Comment: what results of php?

Comment: Complete Code:

<?php

 $input1 = $_GET["input1"];
 $input2 = $_GET["input2"];
 
 $result = $input1 + $input2;
 
 echo "$result";
 

?>



<html>
   <body>
   
  <form action = "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method = "GET" >
    Input1: <input type = "text" name = "input1" />
    Input2: <input type = "text" name = "input2" />
    Result: <input type = "text" name = "result" />
        
    <input type = "submit" />
    

  </form>
      
   </body>
</html>

Comment: @MudassirHussain I've edited your question - you missed some code due to not formatting it, I've made an edit suggestion that will help your question :)

Comment: Mudassir: Are running this through a web server such as WAMP, also is the file extension *.php?

Comment: yes i am running on wamp with extension .php

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by setting `value`

```
<?php 

 $input1 = $_GET["input1"]; 
 $input2 = $_GET["input2"]; 
 $result = $input1 + $input2; 
 echo "$result"; 
 ?> 
 <html> 
    <body> 
        <form action = "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method = "GET" > 
            Input1: <input type = "text" name = "input1" value="<?=$input1?>" /> 
            Input2: <input type = "text" name = "input2" value="<?=$input2?>"/> 
            Result: <input type = "text" name = "result" value="<?=$result?>"/> 
            <input type = "submit" /> 
        </form> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you B.Desai. it is working for me.

Comment: @MudassirHussain if it worked, mark as accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming some sort of adding here

```
<form action = "<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method = "POST" >
         Input1: <input type = "text" value="<?php echo $_POST['input1']; ?>" name = "input1" />
         Input2: <input type = "text" value="<?php echo $_POST['input2']; ?>" name = "input2" />
         Result: <input type = "text" value="<?php echo ($_POST['input1']+ $_POST['input2']); ?>" name = "result" />

         <input type = "submit" />


    </form>
```